# Use input expression in paste0 function in Shiny R

Tags: r, loops, shiny, assign

I have 140 `renderUI` which I want to assign to objects. You could do this manually like this:

```
Filter1 <- input$Filter1
...
Filter140 <- input$Filter140
```

I want to have this more automated, but I can't get the `input$Filter1`:`input$Filter140` in a `paste0`. I tried this:

```
Filters<-c()
for(i in 1:140){
  Filters<-c(paste0('Filter',i),Filters)
}
for(i in Filters){
assign(i,input[[paste0(i)]])
}
```

which I partially got from [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35281806/discretizing-continuous-variable-with-shiny). But it is not working..
Any help would be welcome.

ps. let me know if you need a full `ui.r` and `server.r` example. Although I think this is enough information.

Comment: This could be inconsequential, but you use a capital 'F' in the lower block of code and a lower case 'f' in the higher block of code. Is it saying it can't find `filter1`?

Comment: Thanks, I wrote the first block just quickly but it isn't causing my error. I have made the edit.

Comment: Where do you need the `Filterx`? Can you not avoid using this variable by just calling `input[[paste0(Filter, x)]]` anywhere you would have called `Filterx`?

Comment: with Filterx I just meant Filter1 untill Filter140.

Comment: @Tim_Utrecht I do too, of course. The question remains.

Answer (score 0):

So I believe `assign` doesn't behave with data frames the way you want it to. Try this:

```
Filters <- c()
input <- data.frame(x = "")
for (i in 1:140) {

  Filters <- c(paste0('Filter', i), Filters)

}

tail(Filters)
head(Filters)

for (i in Filters) {

  input[[i]] <- i

}

input <- input[, -1]
```

---

If you want the columns created in the opposite direction, change the line:

```
Filters <- c(paste0('Filter', i), Filters)
```

to

```
Filters <- c(Filters, paste0('Filter', i))
```

Comment: Input is not a `data.frame`, it is created with Shiny. You sure it should work with that?

Comment: And I need the objects Filter1 up to Filter140, not all values in a `data.frame`.

Comment: @Tim_Utrecht Ah, okay, I am not entirely familiar with shiny, but is input some sort of array you can access? The syntax seems very similar to a data frame. And also, are you getting any sort of error?

Comment: It probably behaves like a `data.frame` but you cannot alter it, therefore you need to create new objects. Thanks for your hint, it got me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

After investigating a bit more it did seem to work with the `assign()` and `input[[paste0(i)]]` function:
ui.r:

```
 library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("bins",
                  "Number of bins:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30)
    ),


    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      selectInput("Filter1","Filter1",choices = c("A","B","C"),selected = "A"),
      selectInput("Filter2","Filter2",choices = c("AB","BC","CD"),selected = "AB"),
      selectInput("Filter3","Filter3",choices = c("ABC","BCD","CDF"),selected = "ABC"),
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
))
```

server.r:

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

    # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
    x    <- faithful[, 2]
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
    #Filter1<-input$Filter1
    #print(Filter1)
    #print(input$Filter2)
    for(i in c("Filter1","Filter2","Filter3")){
    #Filter3 <- input[[paste0('Filter3')]]
    assign(i,input[[paste0(i)]])
      print(get(i))
    }
    # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')



  })

})
```